# What is the best way to set a particular bit in a variable in C

Tags: c

Consider a variable `unsigned int a;` in C.

Now say I want to set any i'th bit in this variable to '1'.

Note that the variable has some value. So `a=(1<<i)` will not work.

`a=a+(1<<i)` will work,but I am looking for the fastest way. Anything??

Comment: Why do you think you need the "fastest" way to do this ?

Comment: `a=(1<<i)` will not work as it will clear all the other bits. `a = a+(1<<i)` will not work either, if the bit in question already is set, the addition will clear the bit and make a carry over to the next bit to the left.

Comment: @Lindy : yeah, i know that a=(1<<i) will not work, as I said in my post. But as you said and from other people's comments its better to use OR operator for this.

Answer (score 11):

Bitwise or it. e.g. `a |= (1<<i)`

Comment: Will the compiler convert a |= (1<<i) and a=a+(1<<i) into the same machine code. I mean which is faster?

Comment: @vipin: No, as they aren't equivalent (namely, the result differs when the ith bit is already set). As for performance: The only way to know is to profile! But I'd guess that for 99% of all real applications (i.e. excluding micro-benchmarks doing nothing but the that assignment a ridiculous number of times), you won't be able to measure any real difference.

Comment: Addition is xor with carry. It needs a tiny bit more hardware but I doubt that the `addl` instruction takes more cycles than the `orl` instruction.

Answer (score 8):

Some useful bit manipulation macros

```
#define BIT_MASK(bit)             (1 << (bit))
#define SET_BIT(value,bit)        ((value) |= BIT_MASK(bit))
#define CLEAR_BIT(value,bit)      ((value) &= ~BIT_MASK(bit))
#define TEST_BIT(value,bit)       (((value) & BIT_MASK(bit)) ? 1 : 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

The most common way to do this is:

```
a |= (1 << i);
```

This is only two operations - a shift and an OR. It's hard to see how this might be improved upon.

Answer (score 2):

You should use bitwise OR for this operation.

```
a |= 1 << i;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use

```
a |= (1 << i)
```

But it won't make much of a difference.  Performance-wise, you shouldn't see any difference.

You might be able to try building a table where you map `i` to a bit mask (like `2` => `0x0010` for `0000000000100`), but that's a bit unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a bitwise OR:

```
a |= (1 << i);
```

Note that this does **not** have the same behavior as +, which will carry if there's already a 1 in the bit you're setting.

Answer (score 1):

The way I implemented bit flags (to quote straight out of my codebase, you can use it freely for whatever purpose, even commercial):

```
void SetEnableFlags(int &BitFlags, const int Flags)
{
    BitFlags = (BitFlags|Flags);
}
const int EnableFlags(const int BitFlags, const int Flags)
{
    return (BitFlags|Flags);
}

void SetDisableFlags(int BitFlags, const int Flags)
{
    BitFlags = (BitFlags&(~Flags));
}
const int DisableFlags(const int BitFlags, const int Flags)
{
    return (BitFlags&(~Flags));
}
```

No bitwise shift operation needed.

You might have to tidy up or alter the code to use the particular variable set you're using, but generally it should work fine.