# Most efficent way to add an nth place bit to an int

Tags: algorithm, binary, bit-manipulation, bit

What is the most efficient method of adding an nth place bit to an int?

I use a number to keep track of boolean values for various objects with a corresponding index ie. true for all three objects is 111 in binary or 7 in dec. I need a method to update the boolean value of one of those objects.

My initial thought is to just do:
 value += 2^(index)

But I feel like this may not be the most efficient approach. Is there a better option? Perhaps, using bit twiddling.

Comment: You really have to specify a language for a meaningful answer. For C, C++ and C#, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/7285296/11683.

Comment: Thanks that answered my question

Comment: Ok. Is there a good way to check if bit is set without having to store a bunch of masks and without using the negative number approach so it can be system independent?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7285381/11683

Comment: How do you intend to implement 2^Index ?

Answer (score 0):

Addition here should not be the right operation to perform.

The operation you're (probably) looking for is [bit masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)).

Given your value: `XYZ`, i.e. three bits. If you want to set `Y` to `true` you'll apply a mask with the **OR** operation with the mask `010`.

```
   XYZ
OR 010
   ---
   X1Z
```

But if you want to set `Y` to `false`, use `AND` with the mask `101`:

```
    XYZ
AND 101
    ---
    X0Z
```

The performance of this operation will depend of the language you're using.